# how android OS deals with written file on application uninstall?

Tags: android

friends,

if i have written something on external storage and then i uninstalled application

android will delete that file automatically or i will have to delete it explicitly?

please guide
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Files written to internal storage are removed when the application is uninstalled. Files written to external storage are not. If clean-up is an issue, you could have a second app set up to receive a PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast when the original app is removed. That would only work, of course, if the second app was not removed first.

Comment: if i have written something in external storage then user uninstall application junk will remain there? its a bad thing.... there has to be a way to remove it.